# How to save downloaded data to device's filesystem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm downloading pdf documents from the server:

```
- (void)downloadSingleDocument:(NSURL *)url
{
    [pdfData release];
    pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [req addValue:@"Basic **************=" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Connection did receive data");
    [pdfData appendData:data];
}
```

On connectionDidFinishLoading I want to save downloaded pdf file to filesystem in Documents directory with the same filename as it was on the server.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this methods if you have large file:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
  filepath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:save_name];
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filepath contents:nil attributes:nil];
  file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filepath] retain];// Here file is object of NSFileHandle and its declare in .h File

  [file seekToEndOfFile];

}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

 [file seekToEndOfFile];

 [file writeData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection 
 {
  [file closeFile];
// After you download your data. you can copy your data from here to filesystem. and remove from here
 }
```

Comment: "// After you download your data. you can copy your data from here to filesystem. and remove from here" Could you please describe this process in details? How to copy it to the file system and then remove it?

Comment: @Oleg Sorry for late reply. see this:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFileManagerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009948

Comment: Thanks! This is the working solution I was looking for! Answer accepted!

Comment: Messages to `nil` are ignored.  You don't need to keep checking for `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Use [`NSURLDownload`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html).</s>

Sorry, that is only available on the Mac, not for iOS.

Create a temporary file, and append the received data to it in `connection:didReceiveData:`.  In `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, move the file to the correct place, and in `connection:didFailWithError:`, remove the temporary file.

Comment: But i think NSURLDownload is not available for iOS... Thats what this link says... Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes, I tried myself and realized that NSURLDownload is not supported by iOS. What should I use instead?

Comment: Could you please explain about temporary files in details? I tried Eugene's code, but it doesn't save anything to filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

    NSString *filename = [con.originalRequest.URL lastPathComponent];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:filename];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:pdfData attributes:nil];

}
```

Comment: As a general strategy for downloading PDF files, this isn't great.  You're downloading the entire file to RAM then serialising it to disk.  This means that large PDFs will crash the application as it runs out of memory.

Comment: Also, if you're going to store the default file manager in a local variable, you might as well do it at the beginning of the method and eliminate one of the redundant `defaultManager` calls.

Comment: I get en exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL stringByAppendingString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xee91c00'. Probably I have to use absoluteString to convert NSURL into NSString. Also could you please suggest how can I decode filename from "file%20name.pdf" into "file name.pdf" ?

Comment: Jim is right about the possible file size issue. So if PDF can be really big, then use NSURLDownload. As for the absoluteString - you are right, my bad, was writing this by hand so it slipped. To make convert the name into correct format use - (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding

Comment: Will make NSURLDownload then. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Eugene: Don't use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` (nor `absoluteString`). To get the file path (`NSString`) from a fileURL (`NSURL`), `path` is the only proper method.

Comment: Downvote due to errors in implementation and misleading comments.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Any arguments on why shouldn't I use these? I used absoluteString to get the string value from URL countless times and haven't encountered any problems so far. Can't figure out what's wrong with stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding either.

Comment: don't know why, but it doesn't save files to filesystem, Documents folder is empty when I browse it